# mongodb with nodejs find data in last week with aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want get data last week and always,
in mongo shell i can do it by

```
      {created:{$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 7*24*60*60*1000) }},
```

but how can i do that in nodejs
iam using nodejs,mongodb,aggregation

Comment: What kind of aggregation are you trying to achieve? What is your data model? Which method are you using to formulate the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)?

Answer (score 1):

The way the date of the last one week is arrived at can influence the result. Suppose today's date is `24-Mar-2020`, and I have the following documents from which to select the last one week's data (assuming *today includes* the weeks data):

```
{ "_id" : 1, "createdOn" : ISODate("2020-03-21T12:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "createdOn" : ISODate("2020-03-24T01:56:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 99, "createdOn" : ISODate("2020-03-15T12:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 991, "createdOn" : ISODate("2020-03-18T00:05:00Z") }
```

The following query should select the documents with `_id`'s `1`, `3` and `991`. Here is the code:

```
const coll = db.collection('collection');

const today = new Date();
const ymdStr = today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + today.getDate();
const TODAY_MINUS_7_A = new Date(Date.parse(ymdStr) - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

const TODAY_MINUS_7_B = new Date(new Date() - (7*24*60*60*1000));

console.log("TODAY_MINUS_7 A, B", TODAY_MINUS_7A, TODAY_MINUS_7B);

const matchStage = { $match: { createdOn: { $gte: TODAY_MINUS_7A } } };

col.aggregate( [matchStage] ).toArray( ( err, docs ) => {
    console.log("Aggregation output:");
    console.log( JSON.stringify( docs ) );
    // ...
```

In the `$match` stage try with `TODAY_MINUS_7A` and `TODAY_MINUS_7B` and see the results. The results may not be the same all the time (and it is based upon at what time you run the application). Sometimes, the document with `_id: 991` may *not* be selected, if you are using the `TODAY_MINUS_7B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation like this:

```
db.collecton.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      created: { $gte: new Date().getTime() - 7*24*60*60*1000 }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Sorry bro thats my bad, ISODate() is a mongodb date function. I edited the answer, simply get milli using  javascript function. new Date() & getTime().

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem

```
  Product.aggregate([ {$match :{created: {
        $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime()-7*24*60*60*1000)
     }}}],function(err,products){
       res.send(products)
     })
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some changes; please tell if it is useful. This is mostly about date arithmetic.